# How to update a column in MySQL by modifying current value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to to SQL.I have a table **sales** there is column `mtarget` . I want to increase values in it by 20% . How can we update a column with computed values from same column or in in general any column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to increase values of each row of mtarget by 20% of current values in field

No need for a subquery, that's a straight `update` statement:

```
update sales set mtarget = mtarget * 1.2
```